# What does ./ mean?

Tags: command-line, directory

What does `./` mean?

For example: Does the following command mean moving files from `Gapache2` folder to `sites-available`:

```
root@ip-10-112-55-203:/etc/mds-1.2-beta4/sana/config/etc/Gapache2# mv ./ /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

If not how should this be modified?

I tried getting something from Google Search. But `./` gets ignored by search engines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Unix/linux `.` means the current directory in your case `/etc/mds-1.2-beta4/sana/config/etc/Gapache2`. There are also many shortcuts like:

- `..`: parent directory (`/etc/mds-1.2-beta4/sana/config/etc/`)
- `~`: home folder

So to move all folders and files from `/etc/mds-1.2-beta4/sana/config/etc/Gapache2` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, the command will be like this

```
mv ./* /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

**UPDATE:** [This link](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix1.html) is a good resource for basic UNIX commands

Comment: To move hidden files too, actually you need a more sophisticated glob expression (or different shell settings). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586477/bash-globbing-autoexpand-for-a-few-specific-cases#1586569

Comment: (pretending to be a new user in this comment) *"`./` means the current directory"* What is the difference between `.` and `./` then? I thought that just `.` means the current directory.

Comment: @gertvdijk : Updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

#### About `.`

In UNIX/Linux, `.` means the current directory. You'll also see it listed in `ls` commands:

```
ls -al
total 40348
drwx------  20 root root     4096 Feb  2 23:05 .               <-- there!
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root     4096 Jan 31 20:07 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      322 Dec 16 17:35 20-revert
```

#### Slashes, `./` and the symbolic links

When appending the `/` to it, this has the same meaning as appending a `/` to any other directory name. It will just make sure you're not operating on a file. Generally, this will not be a difference in `cp` and `mv` commands, but you will see a difference when you're using symbolic links. Suppose this structure:

```
.                                                                   
├── a                                                               
├── dir1
│   ├── b
│   └── c
├── dir2
│   └── d
└── symlink -> dir2
```

Then a regular listing will show the link itself

```
ls -l symlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gert gert 4 Feb  3 12:15 symlink -> dir2
```

but appending the `/` will make it list descend into it and showing the contents.

```
ls -l symlink/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gert gert 0 Feb  3 12:15 d
```

This means that when using operations, it's a good thing to append the `/` if you refer to the contents of it or you want to copy/move *into* it by dereferencing the link, rather than replacing the link itself.

See also: [Trailing slashes on symbolic links to directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/trailing-slashes-on-symbolic-links-to-directories)

#### Back to the example

In the example in your question you really want to only move the *contents* of the directory into the other. So, [as aneeshep pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/250825/88802), you should use `mv ./* destdir/`. This is the same as `mv * destdir/` as your shell (Bash) expands the `*` from the current directory by default.

So, I would run it like this (in the source directory):

```
mv * /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```